# Some Issue with Two-way Binding - Not working as expected in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, binding

**Problem: When location is changed via ComboBox cb1 the related location TextBlock does not change to updated value.**

I am self learning and below is experiment code on binding that has 
public EmpDeptViewModel vm;  its initialize on button click event as below

```
private void btn2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { 
vm = new EmpDeptViewModel();
this.Bindings.Update();  }
```

The XAML looks like this.

```
 <ListView x:Name="listview3" ItemsSource="{x:Bind vm.InstanceOfDepartmentData}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="classes:Department">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Margin="5">
                                            <Run Text="DeptNo: " /><Run Text="{x:Bind DeptNo}" />
                                    </TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Margin="5">
                                            <Run Text="DeptName: " /><Run Text="{x:Bind DeptName}" />
                                    </TextBlock>

                                    <TextBlock Margin="5">
                                            <Run Text="Location: " /><Run Text="{x:Bind Location, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                    </TextBlock>

                                    <ComboBox  x:Name="cb1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyLocatonList}, Path=ListofLocationsInsideViewModel, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="LocationName" SelectedValuePath="LocationName"  SelectedValue="{x:Bind Location}"  />
  </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

**Problem: When location is changed via ComboBox cb1 the related location TextBlock does not change to updated value.**

The x:DataType="classes:Department" looks like this.

```
 public class Department : BindableBase
    {   private string _location;
        public Department(int pdeptNo, string pdeptName, string plocation)
        {
            DeptNo = pdeptNo;
            DeptName = pdeptName;
            Location = plocation;
            ListOfDeparmentEmployees = new List<Employee>();    }

        public int DeptNo { get; set; }
        public string DeptName { get; set; }
        public string Location {
            get { return this._location; }
            set { this.SetProperty(ref this._location, value); }
        }
        public List<Employee> ListOfDeparmentEmployees { get; set; }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be bound in the wrong position

In your ComboBox, you set `TwoWay` to the `ItemsSource`. This does not make sense. You cannot change the `Location` if you modify the value of the ComboBox.

Try this:

**Xaml**

```xml
...
<ComboBox  x:Name="cb1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyLocatonList}, Path=ListofLocationsInsideViewModel}" 
           DisplayMemberPath="LocationName" SelectedValuePath="LocationName"  SelectedValue="{x:Bind Location,Mode=TwoWay}"  />
...
```

However, if you write it directly, it will cause an endless loop and then report an error. You need to rewrite the `Location` property of the `Department` class.

**Department.cs**

```cs
...
public string Location
{
    get { return this._location; }
    set 
    {
        if (_location != value)
        {
            this.SetProperty(ref this._location, value);
        }
    }
}
...
```

In addition, please note whether your `BindableBase` base class implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, which is the basis for modifying the UI while modifying the data.

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks a ton Richard Zhang.  That Solved.    Thanks for the 'endless loop' erorr tip.